# obj c uiwebview responsive html

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I want to load responsive html in uiwebview (xcode) , but the page is not adjusting itself as it is responsive html. When i tried same file in other iphone browsers it is displaying adjusted contents i.e. adjusted contents . I dont want to use phonegap for this. How can I display responsive html in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you might check are the following:

1. try to define (or undefine) the viewport in your responsive HTML, e.g.:

   ```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=320,user-scalable=yes,initial-scale=1.0">
   ```
2. check if things improve by setting `scalesPageToFit`:

> If you set this to YES, the webpage is scaled to fit and the user can zoom in and zoom out. If NO, user zooming is disabled. The default value is NO.

But these are just shots in the dark, since you provide no information about the way you are doing things and what exactly does not work. In any case, I hope it helps.

Comment: This is my html code link  [https://www.dropbox.com/s/kcjwv4zzsafmspr/index.html]

Comment: html was not responsive when corrected the meta tags it solves the problem :)

Comment: @umair mian: I am not sure I understood correctly whether setting the viewport fiexed the issue. If so, please accept the answer to let other people know that it works.